# error occurred compiling gcc from source code

Tags: gcc, g++, gcc4.4

Right now the gcc and g++ on my ubuntu 15.10 machine is version 5.2.1. I need to install v4.4 of them for some reason. I downloaded the source code of gcc4.4.7 and configure with this:

```
../configure \
    --disable-checking \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --enable-multiarch \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-threads=posix \
    --program-suffix=4.4 \
    --with-gmp=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-mpc=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lib \
    --without-included-gettext \
    --with-system-zlib \
    --with-tune=generic \
    --prefix=$HOME/bin/android_build
```

I got a makefile and try make but I receive these two errors:

```
../../gcc/toplev.c:536:1: error: redefinition of ‘floor_log2’
../../gcc/toplev.c:571:1: error: redefinition of ‘exact_log2’
```

So how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  Since you've not got an answer for over a month, I'll guess that the answer is 'yes — I got this resolved sufficiently, or circumvented the problem by downloading a pre-compiled version'.

Comment: I just installed an older version ubuntu on virtual machine

Answer (score 7):

I tried to install `gcc 4.4.7`, too, with a newer `gcc` version. I've seen the same errors as you. According to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476370), the problem comes from the flag `-fno-gn89-inline`, which became the default flag for handling inline functions on newer `gcc` versions. As of `gcc 4.3`, the default was `-fgnu89-inline`. So all you need to do, is set the `-fgnu89-inline` flag when compiling.

I tried this with

```
CFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline -g -O2' CXXFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline -g -O2' ./configure
make
```

but I still get the same error. I assume the flags do not get properly forwarded, but I don't know. Then I tried a normal

```
./configure
```

and changed the two lines in the `Makefile` from

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
```

to

```
CC = gcc -fgnu89-inline
CXX = g++ -fgnu89-inline
```

With this, I didn't see the errors any more.

However, I ran into other errors:

```
@itemx must follow @item
```

They are caused by a newer version of `texinfo`, so what you could do is using an older version of `texinfo`. Maybe you could also fix them by hand, I tried it for one case, but I don't know what I'm doing so I didn't follow this path.

Long story short, I guess you are better off by running a virtual machine or a docker image.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`../configure CFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline -g -O2' ...`

It worked for me.

Comment: A little explanation really improves your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*                    //toplev.h 注释下面两个函数 Annotate the following two functions
extern inline int
floor_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
{
  return x ? HOST_BITS_PER_WIDE_INT - 1 - (int) CLZ_HWI (x) : -1;
}

extern inline int
exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
{
  return x == (x & -x) && x ? (int) CTZ_HWI (x) : -1;
}
*/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).